# How to generate a number of vehicles in SUMO when simulation is running?

Tags: python-3.x, sumo

I am using SUMO on Windows. I have the network, the routes and a fixed number of 37000 vehicles in the network. I started my simulation in python and TraCI library as follows:

``

```
sumoBinary = "C:/Program Files/.../sumo-gui"
sumoCmd = [sumoBinary, "-c", "C:/Users/.../my.sumocfg"]
import traci 
traci.start(sumoCmd)
step = 0
while step < 7000:
   traci.simulationStep()
   step += 1
traci.close()
```

My problem is that how could it be possible to add/remove some vehicles to/from those existing ones when the simulation is running. Is it possible at all?
Any hint or reference or link to code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traci.vehicle API has an add and a remove function. So it is just

```
traci.vehicle.remove("myVehicle")
traci.vehicle.add("newVehicle", "routeID")
```

If you have not defined the route for the vehicle up front you can add it with traci.route.add.
 See also https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci._vehicle.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I have the route and I actually needed to add new vehicles to the existing route.